# What HTML tags to use for auto arranging boxes

Tags: css, html

## Background

I am trying to layout a list of article links. Each article has a subject, an image and a small paragraph about the author of the image.

Like this:

```
+----------------+
| Article header |
+----------------+
|                |
|     Image      |
|                |
|          Credit|
+----------------+
```

I am currently using a `div` with multiple `span` elements inside of it. These `span`s then contain the `a`, `img` and `p`.

## Problem

The page is not valid HTML5.

Apparently a `span` cannot have a `p` inside of it.

I do not want to use a `table` even though my 90s knowledge of HTML urges me to. A `table` will not solve my problem either, because I want an uneven number of article links to order themselves naturally and not from left to right. Like this for five linked articles for instance:

```
+------+  +------+
|      |  |      |
|      |  |      |
+------+  +------+
+------+  +------+
|      |  |      |
|      |  |      |
+------+  +------+
     +------+
     |      |
     |      |
     +------+
```

Also if someone resizes the window the article links should collapse into a single column. I also may want to change the width of the articles or of their parent container to make three article links in one line.

## Question

What tag types should I be using to make sure my HTML code is valid HTML5 and with minimal change to the default styles of those elements?

### Addendum

I am not interested in solving anything with a client-side JavaScript library. My pages are tiny and should load fast, the question what tags to choose should be solved in the static HTML content of the page, not after the page has loaded.

Comment: Divs sound like a good choice. Why do you need paragraphs inside spans? It seems counterintuitive - perhaps the other way around would work for you? Finally, I think you might want to take a look at some 'masonry' libraries, [one example here](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Bootstrap may be able to solve your problem, or at least give you some ideas. Take a look at `panels`: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Comment: Here's a bootstrap example: http://plnkr.co/edit/6ziPMrGWZqImUsDwnXCr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flexbox container will do exactly what you just described. I have made a [JFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ghek1ro1/2/) that does what you asked. A flexbox allows you more flexibility than a table as far as aligning content as available space changes, and will collapse nicely into a single column.

Here is the code I used to accomplish this:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="article">
    <span>Article 1</span>
    <div class="image" id="blue">    
    </div>
    <p>
    Credits
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <span>Article 2</span>
   <div class="image" id="red">    
    </div>
    <p>
    Credits
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <span>Article 3</span>
   <div class="image" id="green">   
    </div>
    <p>
    Credits
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <span>Article 4</span>
   <div class="image" id="blue">   
    </div>
    <p>
    Credits
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.article {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 400px;
}
.article span, .article p {
  text-align: center;
}
.article div {
  margin: auto;
}
.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#green {
  background: green;
}
```

Of course you can replace the colored div elements I used with images. You may consider reading up on flexboxes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex. Webkits in that article should be included for different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use elemment ul and li with display inline-table.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Header</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li style="display:inline">Col 1</li>
    <li style="display:inline">Col 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Credit</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I advise you to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to make this job more easy;

Comment: I used to use ul and li, but it kind of screwed up my layout since lists are naturally indented to the right.

Comment: Make a jsfiddler with an example of your code, so i can help you.